# How to call a PyInstaller file in Python code?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to encrypt part of my Python project. This is a file where I store DB credentials and generate DB connection variables:

```
user = ''
pass = ''
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user=user, password=password ...)
```

I use "connection" variable in the rest part of the project.

I have generated a binary file with PyInstaller from Python file and tried to do like this:

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.call(["./dist/connections/connections"]))
print(connection)
```

No success :|

**QUESTION**

Can I call the binary file in Python and get "connection" var to Python environment?

Comment: Never store passwords in your code (encrypted or not) — it's useless..

Comment: @l'L'l Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the db connection local, or remote? need more details on what exactly you are doing.